# Meaning of flickering light on outlet tester

Tags: receptacle

What does it mean when a gfci outlet tester shows the following light combination;

Bright "open ground" light and a dim/flickering "open neutral" light. I understand the open ground as there is no grounding wire, but I don't understand the dim open neutral.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Outlet testers indicate status by the combination of lights – “Correct” is just a combination of the two yellow/amber lights for “open ground” and “open neutral”. So yours is actually flickering between the “correct” and “open ground” states, meaning there *is* some sort of ground connection, just a very poor/unreliable one that shouldn’t be used.

[This article from the Circuit Detective](http://www.thecircuitdetective.com/outlet_tester_readings.htm) has an explanation of all the possible combinations of lights on a typical outlet tester, including dim/flickering ones.

Comment: Or the *flickering* could be due a faulty neon lamp in the tester. I suggest checking the tester in a known-good socket.